# How to access Azure storage account Via Azure windows Virtual Machine Through Managed Identity

Tags: powershell, jwt, azure-virtual-machine, azure-data-lake, azure-managed-identity

I am Trying to Access Azure Storage Account Via Azure Windows VM.
I followed This Microsoft Document Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-datalake

I followed almost All steps That Mentioned In the above Document Link& JWT Access Token also Generated Successfully But My Commands For Uploading/Downloading Files are Throwing Errors.

Error: InvalidAuthenticationInfoAuthentication information is not given in the correct format

[image]

Please Correct me if i  Used any wrong Commands For Download/Upload Files Via Virtual Machines Through Managed Identity

Commands Used For Generating JSW Token:
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://adlsrg.blob.core.windows.net/' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$AccessToken = $content.access_token

Comment: Does the VM MSI have Storage Blob Data Reader role on the storage account or container?

Comment: Yes i given contributor role for that

Comment: No. Not Contributor. Have you given it Storage Blob Data Contributor?

Comment: The error says remote name could not be resolved.  This means you do not have a route to the VM.  You need to get a route before the authorization will work.  Make sure you can PING the IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access storage accounts, you need to generate access token for  `https://storage.azure.com` resource.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one VM and **enabled** system-assigned managed identity like below:

[image]

Assign **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to VM under your storage account as below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Storage accounts -> Your account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment*

[image]

Now connect to VM and run below PowerShell commands to get access token:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://storage.azure.com' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"} 
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json 
$AccessToken = $content.access_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

To upload **file** to storage account, you can use below script:

```
$file = "C:\Users\sri\Desktop\hello.txt" #File path
$name = (Get-Item $file).Name

$url="https://sristorageacc5.blob.core.windows.net/sri/$($name)"

$RequestHeader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$RequestHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $AccessToken")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob")

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers $RequestHeader -InFile $file
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, file uploaded to container **successfully** like below:

[image]

Comment: can you please Share Script for Download Blob to VM C drive?

Comment: Kindly refer to this https://dzone.com/articles/download-blob-to-azure-vm-using-custom-script-exte

Comment: Hi Sourav, i need to download Adls File Using Managed Identity but, https://dzone.com/articles/download-blob-to-azure-vm-using-custom-script-exte link Using Connection String For download....

Comment: HI SRI, Thank You! Your Answer Is Working Perfectly! please share one more script for Downloading File From Adls To Local....